# How can I use OpenCV with Flask to capture video/image from the Client?

Tags: python, opencv, flask

I am trying to create a Flask application which will allow the users to use their webcam as a motion detector and I have a working code in OpenCV which does detect motion but right now it uses the cam of the local machine only (i.e. server). I don't know how to capture images/video from the client instead of the server and then pass it on for motion detection with OpenCV.

I found this article https://kirupa.com/html5/accessing_your_webcam_in_html5.htm which uses HTML5 and JS to capture feed from the client but it doesn't show a way to use it with OpenCV.

Here's the code for the route in the flask app

```
@app.route('/camera')
@login_required
def camera():
    return Response(get_frame(), mimetype='multipart/x-mixed- replace; boundary=frame')
```

And here's the 'get_frame()' passed in the Response above

```
def get_frame():
    camera_port = 0  # Assigns which webcame to detect if user has more than one webcam
    camera = cv2.VideoCapture(camera_port)  # Creates a camera object
    first_frame = None  # This variable will store the first image as a base image for comparing with images thereafter

    # Starts the while loop to stream feed
    while True:
        status = 0
        check, frame = camera.read()
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)  # Converts to gray scale
        gray = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (21, 21), 0)
        ....
        ....
        imgencode = cv2.imencode('.jpg',frame)[1]
        image_data = imgencode.tostring()
        yield (b'--frame\r\n'
             b'Content-Type: text/plain\r\n\r\n' + imageData + b'\r\n')
```

Comment: Hi! Did you find a way to do this ?

Comment: No I still haven't, but I think this will be better implemented with JavaScript at the front end rather than trying to achieve this with Python or Flask. I will post my answer when I find a solution.